# When to use DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server

When is it good to use `SELECT DISTINCT ..` and when not?

Basically whenever I see `DISTINCT` keyword I start to get cautious as most of the cases it is ends up finding that actual query has some problems (not selective enough, bad joins, incorrect logic and so on).

Do you have similar experience or is it just me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` is sometimes an indication that someone has 'fixed' a query that returns duplicate rows in a naive way. This (mis-)use is probably more common among those with relatively little database experience.

That said, some people (Chris Date, for example) argue that `DISTINCT` should be the default qualifier for `SELECT`; we should have to write `SELECT ALL` to return a non-relational result (relations do not contain duplicate tuples by definition).

My view is that there is nothing *inherently* wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT`. It can be the most natural way to express a query. If the execution plan and performance is acceptable, I see no sensible reason to mandate that it should *never* be used.

At the same time, it is clearly wrong to simply add `DISTINCT` at the top level of a complex query to eliminate duplicates at a late stage, when the query should be simply written more efficiently.

Comment: And @MikaelEriksson (and reading your comment below, also Rob Farley) has demonstrated some cases where using `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`, while yielding the same results, can do so in a much less efficient way (filtering too late).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use the `select distinct` only if you do not need the result of a function that forces the usage of `group by`. For example if you have a table with `country_id` and `city_name` and you only want to know which `country_id`s are present and you are not interested in how many (most of the times a sub-select). If `select distinct` is there to 'fix' a problem then you are likely to get a bad performance in return.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY lets you use aggregate functions, like AVG, MAX, MIN, SUM, and COUNT. DISTINCT just removes duplicates.

Performance wise there is no difference in SQL SERVER. http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/distinct-vs-group

Keep in mind that there are performance differences in some other dbs.

Chose what is more readable. If you're just looking to remove duplicates use DISTINCT. If you want to use aggregate functions use GROUP BY.

Readability is extremely important for other developers to understand your code and not introduce bugs.

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates and rank (enumerate) the remaining distinct items, with GROUP BY you can do both in one go, with DISTINCT you will have to use a derived table/CTE/temporary table.

Comment: The second paragraph is not accurate. There can easily be a performance difference in SQL Server between distinct and group by. For one example see http://blogs.msmvps.com/robfarley/2007/03/24/group-by-v-distinct-group-by-wins/